# buildroot config to enable usb ports of raspberry pi CM4 IO Board

Tags: raspberry-pi, usb, raspberry-pi4, buildroot

I made a custom os for the raspberry pi CM4 with IO board using **buildroot**.
`make raspberrypicm4io_64_defconfig`
`make menuconfig`
`make all`

Buildroot OS boots with no errors.

However, when i flash the OS image to the CM4 the **USB ports do not work**, on the IO board.

I edited the boot partition and added `dtoverlay=dwc2,dr_mode=host` and removed all unnecessary cables connected to the IO board like the micro-USB cable, but the USB ports still don't work.
I can confirm the the USB ports work, because i tested them with the official rasbian os.

Comment: "*I can confirm the the USB ports work, because i tested them with the official rasbian os.*" -- Then you have a baseline for comparison with what you built. Compare the kernel boot logs. Compare the Device Trees; if you can't find the source file(s), then use **/proc/device-tree/** of the running system.